# Javascript Testing With Unique ID's

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am kinda new to testing javascript and I was wondering what is the best way to go about testing something where a unique ID is generated.

EDIT:

I don't really want to test the ID I want to make sure that the action returns the right results when the createQuestion function is called. But the test will fail because the ID will never match since it is generated in the function.

My current code looks like this.

```js
//------- Action Creator --------//

export const createQuestion = function (inputType) {
  const hasOptions = /radio/g.test(inputType);
  return {
    type: types.CREATE_QUESTION,
    question: {
      id: uuid.v1(),
      priority: null,
      title: null,
      tip: null,
      required: false,
      isSaved: false,
      hasOptions: hasOptions,
      input: {
        type: inputType,
        options: []
      }
    }
  };
};


//------- TESTS --------//
test('Question Actions', nest => {

  nest.test('Create Question', function (assert) {
    const msg = 'Questions was Created';

    const question = {
      id: 1,
      priority: null,
      title: null,
      tip: null,
      required: false,
      isSaved: false,
      hasOptions: false,
      input: {
        type: 'text',
        options: []
      }
    };

    const expectedAction = {
      type: types.CREATE_QUESTION,
      question
    };


    const actualAction = actions.createQuestion('text');
    assert.deepEqual(actualAction, expectedAction, msg);
    assert.end();
  });
```

Since the Unique Id is generated in the Action Creator it is impossible to mock unless I change the ID after the function returns with the action.

With something like this

```
const changeUUID = obj => {
  const newobj = {...obj};
  newobj.question.id = 1;
  return newobj;
};
```

Comment: What about the id do you want to test?

Comment: I don't really want to test the ID I want to make sure that the action returns the right results when the createQuestion function is called. But the test will fail because the ID will never match since it is generated in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless You are interested in id to have a specific value, it is totally fine to exclude it from `expectedAction`.

```
assert.ok(actualAction.question.id);

delete actualAction.question.id;

assert.deepEqual(actualAction, expectedAction, msg);
```

Comment: I believe it would be `actualAction.question.id`

Comment: Yep, my fault. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome that works and is a little smarter than the way I was thinking about it. The Ids don't really matter its the rest of the content that does. I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing any unneeded manipulation to the returned data.